# c++ reload function while application running

Tags: c++, function, reload

i have a function that read config file and i wanted to reload this function to get the new variables

```
void readConfigFile()
{
    ifstream File;
    File.open("config.txt", ios::in);
    while (!File.eof()){
        string line;
        int Hour;
        int Minuts;
        getline(File, line);
        File >> Hour >> Minuts;
    }
    File.close();
}

int main()
{
    readConfigFile();
    while (1) {
        time_t now;
        struct tm *current;
        now = time(0);
        current = localtime(&now);
        if( current->tm_hour == Hour && current->tm_min == Minuts){
            std::cout <<  "Done" << std::endl;
        }
        Sleep(5000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

how i can reload this readConfigFile() function to get the new Hour / Minuts while application running

for example

```
if(Clicked Button){

reload readConfigFile();

}
```

while i searching on internet about reload

i found that i can do that with operators overloading

but i couldnt use it

i am still begainner :(

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the problem is that the variables `Hour` and `Minuts` (sic) are *local* to the `readConfigFile` function.

That means that whenever you call `readConfigFile` you only change those local variables, not whatever global variabled you might have.

If those variables were global, then you just have to call `readConfigFile` again, and it will read into them again.

Comment: so how i can recall readConfigFile again and it is already called before

Comment: @beshoyMounir It's a normal function, there is nothing in that function that I can see that prevents it to be called multiple times. Just like you call the `localtime` function multiple times in the loop in `main`, you can call your function multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If I did not misunderstand your request, I think you have already wrote the code yourself.

Are you asking how can you load your new Hour and Min into your program while it is running in `main()`'s `while` loop?

```
int main()
{
    readConfigFile();
    while (1) {

    // Read the Config file here
    if (Button Clicked)
    {
        readConfigFile();
    }

    time_t now;
    struct tm *current;
    now = time(0);
    current = localtime(&now);  
    if( current->tm_hour == Hour && current->tm_min == Minuts){
        std::cout <<  "Done" << std::endl;
    }
    Sleep(5000);
}
```

**EDIT:**

My fault of didn't notice the Hour and Min are local vars...

Please change them to Global vars.